# How to use NavigationLink inside SwiftUI sheet

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-sheet

I have 4 SwiftUI View:

- The **FirstView** opens the **SecondView** using a sheet:

  ```
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            SecondView()
        }
  ```
- The **SecondView** opens the **ThirdView** using a sheet too:

  ```
    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            ThirdView()
    }
  ```

My expectations: I want **ThirdView** opens **FourthView** using NavigationLink (on full screen with Back button in the left corner):

```
            NavigationLink(destination: FourthView()) {
                Text("Open FourthView")
            }
```

but I'm having trouble with the view hierarchy. If I want to use NavigationLink, somewhere I have to define NavigationView.
If I define NavigationView in the SecondView like this:

```
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            NavigationView {
                ThirdView()
            }
        }
```

, I have *sheet view* with Back button, but I want a *full screen view* with Back button.

Could you help me with this views hierarchy, where should I put NavigationView?

Comment: So, basically what you want is that **simultaneously**: 1) Third view dismisses itself *AND* 2) First view navigates to Fourth view. You could use `NavigationStack` with a path, available only since iOS 16.0. Otherwise, use some bindings with `if` clauses in the view.